# iPad volume keeps rising all by itself

Tags: ios, ipad, audio, sound-volume

I've searched in settings and tried turning my iPad off, but nothing has helped.

It's so freaking annoying I am scared I will get in trouble.

I am not sure what kind of iPad mine is (apparently there are iPad Airs and numbered ones like iPhones but I think it is an older version then those). 
My iPad is about 4 years and a few months old.

It seems to happen when I am watching YouTube in a browser (not on an app).

**What else can I try to resolve this problem?**

Comment: You can determine the exact model of your iPad by looking towards the bottom back [like this](http://s19735.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/blog-ipad-model-guide1.jpg).

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you perceive the volume to have risen or the change is reflected in the OS volume level indicator as well?

Comment: Any chance you have iPad lying in landscape mode, and the volume rocker is being pressed accidentally? It's an obvious thing to ask but not so obvious it is happening. My wife's iPad did this a few days ago when she tilted the device forward to let my son see the screen - tilting it pressed the button against the table, changing volume to 0.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this apple support discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7919577)

> I understand that the volume controls on your iPhone are not working
>   properly, and I'm happy to help. You can follow these instructions,
>   and contact Apple Support if you still need assistance.
>
> If the volume buttons, Ring/Silent switch, or Side Switch doesn't work
>   On an iPhone, the volume buttons and Ring/Silent switch are on the
>   left side of the device. The buttons on other iPhone models are
>   similar. On an iPad, the volume buttons and Side Switch are on the
>   right side of the device. If any of these buttons or switches don't
>   work, follow these steps. After each step, see if you still need help:
>   Unlock your device. Some buttons don't work from the Lock screen.
>   Check for debris or dirt around the button or switch and clean with a
>   soft cloth. Remove all protective films and cases that might interfere
>   with the button or switch.